# What's wrong with this nested switch statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

This statement is returning all the numbers from 1-100, but is not applying fizz-buzz rules. Not sure why. Can you offer an explanation?

```
for (var number = 1; number <= 100; number++) {
  switch(number) {
  case number % 3 == 0:
    console.log('Fizz');
    break;
  case number % 5 == 0:
    console.log('Buzz');
    break;
  case number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 == 0:
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
    break;
  default:
    console.log(number);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/e2pptuno/ <- you need to compare agains `true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing the number with boolean expressions. The switch would be equivalent with:

```
if (number == (number % 3 == 0)) {
  console.log('Fizz');
} else if (number == (number % 5 == 0)) {
  console.log('Buzz');
} else if (number == (number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 == 0)) {
  console.log('FizzBuzz');
} else {
  console.log(number);
}
```

Use `if` statements instead of a switch, and check the double condition first:

```
if (number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 == 0) {
  console.log('FizzBuzz');
} else if (number % 3 == 0) {
  console.log('Fizz');
} else if (number % 5 == 0) {
  console.log('Buzz');
} else {
  console.log(number);
}
```

Comment: Ah. Yea. In this case the if statements seem to be much more expressive of the intended result. Thanks. Would you say that switch is better used in instances where there is a specific and definable case (as opposed to a series of possible cases)?

Comment: @Zack: Yes, a switch fits better when you have specific values to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

number is matched against expression of case so if number is 3, it does not match "number % 3 == 0" because "number % 3 == 0" is true, not 3

Answer (score -1):

Your code will never reach the case:

```
case number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 == 0
```

because it will have already made it into the first case:

```
case number % 3 == 0:
```

One way around this would be to change the statements to:

```
case number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 != 0
case number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 != 0
```